# Unable to have different font size between "label" and "key"

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have two queries.

1) I am trying to have different font size for `label` and `key`. Strangely unable to do so for the below MWE though the syntax seems correct from there manual.

Is there any obvious mistake(s)?

2) How to have Z-Axis also labeled with its ztics in the far right z-column. I was not successful in getting it done using z2tics.

Gnuplot Version (in Ubuntu 10.04):

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.4 patchlevel 0
last modified March 2010
System: Linux 2.6.32-73-generic

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2010
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others
```

MWE:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset

set term postscript eps enhanced font "Helvetica"10 
set output "output.eps"
set autoscale
set grid nopolar
set grid xtics nomxtics ytics nomytics noztics nomztics nox2tics nomx2tics noy2tics nomy2tics nocbtics nomcbtics
set grid layerdefault lt 1 lc rgb "black" linewidth 0.200 ,  lt 2 lc rgb "black" linewidth 0.200
set style data lines

set xlabel "X-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25'
set xlabel  offset character 3, -2, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set xlabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set xrange [ 1 : 4 ] noreverse nowriteback
set xtics 1 

set ylabel "Y-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25'
set ylabel  offset character -3, -2, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set ylabel font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set yrange [ 1 : 4 ] noreverse nowriteback
set ytics 1 

set zlabel "Z-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25'
set zlabel  offset character 2, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set zlabel font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate by 90
set zrange [ 0 : 16 ] noreverse nowriteback

set key top left horizontal box spacing 1.75 at 2.5,5,18
set dgrid3d 4,4 splines

splot \
"data.dat" using 2:1:3 ti "Surface 1" with lines lc rgb "red" ,\
"data.dat" using 2:1:4 ti "Surface 2" with lines lc rgb "blue"
```

Data File (data.dat):

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
1   1   4.869679347 3.972865464                         
1   2   5.525583065 4.021323159
1   3   5.301208942 4.030586248                                 
1   4   5.196368577 4.013930969
2   1   8.431558641 5.219640683
2   2   8.541050259 4.604480742
2   3   8.959566461 4.473923458
2   4   8.553504132 4.286745078
3   1   11.12925205 7.254675355
3   2   11.59059432 7.374715619
3   3   10.67896866 7.058545226
3   4   11.09279485 6.728441639
4   1   15.57308092 10.92185317
4   2   15.26268993 10.59114975
4   3   14.88192486 10.1134937
4   4   14.74660555 10.15774687
```

Output File:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the `font` for the `xlabel` and `ylabel` you overwrite it twice with the following calls, which contain something like `set xlabel font ""`. Merge those calls, which are mainly superfluous:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset

set term postscript eps enhanced font "Helvetica,10" color
set output "output.eps"

set xlabel "X-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25' offset character 3, -2, 0
set xrange [ 1 : 4 ]
set xtics 1 

set ylabel "Y-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25' offset character -3, -2, 0
set yrange [ 1 : 4 ]
set ytics 1 

set zlabel "Z-Axis" font 'Helvetica,25' offset character 2, 0, 0
set zrange [ 0 : 16 ]

set key top left horizontal box spacing 1.75 at 2.5,5,18
set dgrid3d 4,4 splines

splot \
"data.dat" using 2:1:3 ti "Surface 1" with lines lc rgb "red" ,\
"data.dat" using 2:1:4 ti "Surface 2" with lines lc rgb "blue"
```

[image]

Concerning point 2): gnuplot doesn't have a z2 axis (also it doesn't have a x2 and y2axis in 3D), and you cannot select the position of the zaxis.